# Appium 2 - can't connect to server from Java Code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I had to update Selenium and Appium at my test project. My current configuration is:

- Selenium 4
- Appium 2

After all necessary changes mentioned at migration guides my Java Tests are not working. It's not possible to connect to Appium Server (started via CLI). Im using real Devices

It's not working for both Android and iOS (UIAutomator2 and XCUITest drivers). Drivers versions are correct in context of Appium 2 and my Xcode version

Appium Inspector is working fine and Im able to connect to both devices (iOS and Android)

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'MYPC.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14a6:1f6d:5e7b:a5f3%en0'
```

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '4.5.3', revision: '4b786a1e430'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.2', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
```

Command to start server:

```
Appium server --address 127.0.0.1 --allow-cors
```

Capabilities and Driver initialisation

```
XCUITestOptions options = new XCUITestOptions()
                .setUdid(deviceUdid)
                .setPlatformName(platformName)
                .setPlatformVersion(platformVersion)
                .setDeviceName(deviceName)
                .setAutomationName("XCUITest")
                .setXcodeCertificate(new XcodeCertificate("SOME VALUE", "Apple Development"))
                .setSafariIgnoreFraudWarning(true)
                .setNewCommandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(75))
                .setBundleId(bundleID);

return new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"), options);
```

Any suggestions? Did you had similar issue?

BR
Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

Try removing last slash from your URL.

So it becomes:

```
return new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
```

Comment: I also tried without the slash at the end of URL - the same issue. At the moment without any changes code is hanging before first method was called

Comment: Is your driver static? What about the server logs?

I also see `Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver` in your logs, but you return iOS driver

Comment: I put wrong logs, cuz I tired at both, Android and iOS. For AndroidDriver I have similar method to return it using UIAutomator2Options. Server is not logging anything - looks like Java Client not send any proper message to server. Driver is not static, it's returned from Factory according to used device platform name